# Change HTML checkbox from unchecked to check

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

```
<table>
    <td style="width:40%;" bgcolor="#FFDDDD">
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="crs_domain[1]" unchecked="">
        Math;&nbsp;
    </label>            
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="crs_domain[2]" unchecked="">
        Science;&nbsp;  
    </label>            
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="crs_domain[3]" unchecked="">
        Bio;&nbsp;  
    </label>            
    </td>
</table>
```

I am doing tedious work about updating tick the checkbox according an excel file.

Example: Science and Bio need to be tick. Than i need to tick the checkbox of Science and Bio, after that submit.

I realize that i can change the html element from **unchecked** to **checked**, then click Submit it will be the same result.

```
<label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="crs_domain[2]" checked="">
        Science;&nbsp;  
</label>
```

So i wanna write an Extension to do stuff like: when i copy "Science, Bio". The extension will auto change my html element, than i just need to copy the subject who need change, than submit, no need tick one by one.

[image: test]

I test `var x = document.getElementsByTagName("label")` on browser console,  `x[1]` will be the element. But cannot `x[1].checked` let **unchecked** become **checked**.

So my question is how to let **unchecked** become **checked**.

Comment: Why you needed extension? I think you can achieve this with Javascript/JQuery?

Comment: If you want to change the *HTML* you have to use [`removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) and [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) on the actual input.

Comment: @TechieBoy becuz this website is not mine, i'm just a user of this website.~

Comment: in that case I cannot change the html and I must use same html tag. I will update my example

Answer (score 2):

```
   var secondInput = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];

   secondInput.checked = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

After submit trigger `SetCheckBox()`. Also set id of each `checkbox`

```js
function SetCheckBox() {
  document.getElementById("science").checked = true;
  document.getElementById("bio").checked = true;
}
```

```html
<body onload="SetCheckBox()">
<table>
    <td style="width:40%;" bgcolor="#FFDDDD">
    <label>
    <input id="math" type="checkbox" value="1">
        Math;&nbsp;
    </label>            
    <label>
        <input id="science" type="checkbox" value="2">
        Science;&nbsp;  
    </label>            
    <label>
        <input id="bio" type="checkbox" value="3">
        Bio;&nbsp;  
    </label>            
    </td>
</table>
</body>
```